# Same index in column chart Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to kind of merge 2 series in a column chart, while keeping a separate color and legend?
I have 4 series. "Deze week" and "Gisteren" are separate series, but I want to show the black column on the same "index" as the darkblue columns.

Visually: Right now there's a gap between the columns on "Wo", but I want to get rid of this gap.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enable the `centerInCategory` option:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            centerInCategory: true
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/24tzLg6p/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.centerInCategory